# Unity Android manifest merge issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I am trying to build an android app, however something goes wrong with merging manifests. When I check the:

> PROJECT\Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest.xml

It seems like my Manifest with compare to the older ones is missing some content. As far as I know to final manifest should contain elements from Unity "part" and from other plugins (in my case Google Play Games) as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html). In section "How Unity produces the Android Manifest". When i look at my actual Manifest i can spot that line is missing:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
            android:value="\ 0.9.50" />
```

but there are also some more which seems to be missing but I exactly do not know which (about 12 lines). The second thing that happens is that the App icon is lacking.

I have already tried :

- Assets -> Play Services Resolver -> Android Resolver -> Force Resolve
- Adding manually missing lines it is rather hit-or-miss approach.

Google Play Games plugin manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This file was automatically generated by the Google Play Games plugin for Unity
     Do not edit. -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.example.games.mainlibproj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16" />



    <application>



        <!-- The space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="\ {MY_ID}" />

        <!-- Keep track of which plugin is being used -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion"
            android:value="\ 0.9.50" />

        <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Final manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="{package name}" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:isGame="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="{build id}" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Unity Cloud Build service is building good final manifest (I used apktool to get it back from .apk):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" package="{package name}">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.high_performance" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon" android:isGame="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
        <activity android:configChanges="density|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|layoutDirection|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true"/>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="{build id}"/>
        <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0"/>
        <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="true"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:name="com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.PurchaseActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:enableVrMode="com.google.vr.vrcore/com.google.vr.vrcore.common.VrCoreListenerService" android:name="com.unity.purchasing.googleplay.VRPurchaseActivity" android:theme="@style/VrActivityTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.vr.vrcore.ACTION_NONE"/>
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.DAYDREAM"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <service android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService" android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION"/>
        <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.hippogames.simpleandroidnotifications.Controller"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mcc|mnc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|touchscreen|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value=" {app id}"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion" android:value=" 0.9.50"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I want to do something with the editor to build same manifest as before/unity cloud build

Comment: Is Unity producing an error (usually the build fails, with a large debug). If so, please post that here. Also, paste both manifests. It's hard to tell without this.

Comment: Build goes with success, the only one thing that goes wrong is that app is crashing on start and the icon is gone. Trying to debug this I've noticed that manifest looks weird. I'll post both manifests in a sec.

Comment: Added manifests, as far as I know it should contain 3 lines from GPG manifest.

Comment: Nothing particularly off here far as I can see. Could you post the build output from the editor? It's saved to the editor log file.

Comment: @roffensive I'm having the same issue (Unity ignoring Google Play Games plugin manifest when merging). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of `AndroidManifest.xml` and place it in the folder.

> To use an Android Manifest that you have created outside of Unity,
>
> import your Android Manifest file to the following location:
>   *Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml*
>
> This overrides the default Unity-created Manifest.

[Unity Override Android Manifest](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-manifest.html)